# send lon lat data from javascript to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to front end developing. On client side I am trying to type in an adress, and extract the corresponding long lat coordinates, in order to send them back to flask. How can I send long lat data from Javascript to flask? Here is my code

```
$("#yes").click(function(event) {

  var text = $('#bt1').val();


  $.get(url + 'text=' + text, function(data) {
    var result1= JSON.parse(data);


    $.ajax({
      url: url2,
      type: "POST",
      data: JSON.stringify(data),    <-- here I want to put long lat data 
      dataType: 'json',      
      success: function(response){
        console.log("ok");
      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        console.log("error");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

On server side this is my set up:

```
@app.route('/something', methods=['POST'])
def something():
   conn = g.db.cursor()
   return null
```

But I get an Error Message of type 404.

Comment: youre using a `get` request which is for getting data from the server. You need to use a `post` request and send the data as part of that. You also need to set up your flask server to have a `url` to receive the `post` request.

Comment: I need the `get` request for getting the adressname from the database, but as a second step I want to pass the long lats based on the user input adress back to the server. This is my set up in flask `@app.route('adress/, methods =[GET]): ...`

Comment: 404 is page not found. Also you are posting to `loalhost` not `localhost`

Comment: If youre learning `flask` id highly recommend [miguel grinbergs tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world). Parts of it are out of date but its still a great tutorial

Comment: @Craicerjack thanks for the link. I just changed localhost for the plattform. In my code there is the right host number.

Comment: What is returning the the 404 error message? Also your `post` request is in your loop, which is in your `get` request. Is this correct?

Comment: No my post request is not in the loop, but in the get request in order to catch the long lat objects and pass them to flask. If I execute my code it returns the `console.log(error)` message

Comment: That means your issue is on the flask side, `localhost:5000/long_lat` cant be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it! For those who have the same problem here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: my_url,
  type: "POST",
  data: {"x": lat, "y": long},          
  success: function(response){
    console.log("something");
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
    console.log("error");
  }
});
```